# GruntJS Warning: URNs do not have any generally defined hierarchical components

Tags: sass, gruntjs, filepath

I'm on Windows and using GruntJS for a project. I'm coming across a warning after updating any .scss file:

> Warning: URNs do not have any generally defined hierarchical
>   components Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

The main CSS file ends up being borked leaving the site unstyled.

I cannot find any information on what the warning means or on fixing it.

How can I fix this? Could it have something to do with directory separators (e.g. Windows uses backslashes)?

Comment: What packages do you use in your Gruntfile? It's very strange

Comment: "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.3.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.5.3",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-prompt": "^1.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.1.5",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.7.2",
    "URIjs": "^1.13.1",
    "MD5": "^1.2.1"

Comment: I've tried using --force but the error still persists. the Cygwin bash says this: Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
Warning: URNs do not have any generally defined hierarchical components Used --force, continuing.

Comment: Please do not add back in irrelevant tags, they were removed for a reason (unless you think an expert on "concat" or "minification" is going to help you solve your problem).

Comment: Actually, yes they could because the problem seems to deal with how filepaths are being handled/concatenated depending on the OS. After digging some more, there seems to be an issue with packages: grunt-contrib-concat and URI.js. The error is actually coming from URI.js v1.13.1, line 1831. I'm not sure how to fix it to take into account different OS environments.